# Stroking paths using a pattern color to simulate brush texture

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-graphics

I am making a finger painting app and I am having a hard time giving my brush a nice brush-like feel and texture.

I have this code:

```
    UIColor * brushTexture = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Brush_Black.png"]]; 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brushTexture.CGColor);
```

but my output is like this:
[image: Image of Mouse]

The texture of my brush is tiled. How can I make it fit to the stroke Size and stop the tiling of the image?

Comment: Have you discovered the answer?

Comment: Have u ever found solution to this??

Comment: @Bruno there! i answered! hope it'll help!

Comment: @Dimple check my answer hope it'll work for you. :)

Comment: Thanks @SeongHo for quick reply.. U can accept your answer.. I will try.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here i found a solution!

```
    UIImage *texture = [UIImage imageNamed:"brush.png"]    
    CGPoint vector = CGPointMake(currentPoint.x - endPoint.x, currentTPoint.y - endPoint.y);
    CGFloat distance = hypotf(vector.x, vector.y);
    vector.x /= distance;
    vector.y /= distance;
    for (CGFloat i = 0; i < distance; i += 1.0f) {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(endPoint.x + i * vector.x, endPoint.y + i * vector.y);
        [texture drawAtPoint:p blendMode:blendMode alpha:0.5f];
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample for what this looked like?  I know I am asking for a lot considering this was over a year ago, but I am also interested in this area and I am evaluating several papers/posts online for implementation.

Comment: Performance on this was GREAT for me, and such a simple solution. Thank You!